# Problem involving supremum inequality

Tags: inequality, supremum-and-infimum

I believe there is something wrong in my proof below because the result is not correct, can anyone help me spot that out?

$$ |f(x)|\geq f(x) \\ \text{So } |f(x)| \text{ is an upper bound of } f(x)
\\
|f(x)|\geq \sup f(x)
\\
\text{Also, } \sup |f(x)| \geq |f(x)|
\\
\sup |f(x)|\geq\sup f(x)$$

Comment: Define $\sup |f(x)|$.

Comment: Should be $\sup \{|f(x)| : x\in X\}$

Comment: $|f(x)|$ is an upper bound for just the particular value $f(x)$, not for $\{f(y): y \in X\}$.

Comment: Oh I see the problem, thanks!

Comment: But then is the inequality on the last line correct? As is seems intuitive.

Comment: The problem is it happens to be flipped, the inequality sign.

Comment: Yes, the last line is correct.

Comment: When I am working on integrability of $|f|$ provided  that $f$ is integrable, I saw this inequality $$ \sup_I\vert f\vert-\inf_I\vert f\vert\leq \sup_I f-\inf_I f\ $$

Comment: That looks like a complete reverse of what I have done so far.